# np.where Not Working in my Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I have an np.where problem using Pandas that is driving me crazy and I can't seem to solve through Google, the documentation, etc.

I'm hoping someone has insight.  I'm sure it isn't complex.

I have a df where I'm checking the value in one column - and if that value is 'n/a' (as a string, not as in .isnull()), changing it to another value.

`Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'] == 'n/a'`

returns:

```
70      True
88     False
90      True
145     True
156     True
181     True
191     True
200     True
219     True
223    False
Name: MarketCap, dtype: bool
```

so that part works.

but this:

```
Full_Names_Test_2['NewColumn'] = np.where(Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'] == 'n/a', 7)
```

returns:

```
ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to pass the boolean mask and the (two) values columns:

```
np.where(Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'] == 'n/a', 7)
# should be
np.where(Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'] == 'n/a', Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'], 7)
```

*See the [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) docs.*

or alternatively use [the `where` Series method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'].where(Full_Names_Test_2['MarketCap'] == 'n/a', 7)
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot.  I think I didn't grasp the basic syntax of the np.where method.  Now I see clearly. thanks again!

Comment: @Windstorm1981 fwiw, I think the docs on this method & this error message could be a LOT clearer. It's not obvious (enough, IMO) that the 2nd argument is required.

Comment: This error also arises if you put `x` and `y` in an iterable (i.e. `[x,y]`) even though the Docstring contains `numpy.where(condition, [x, y])`