# How to plot the string values on the graph in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I am doing the data segmentation where I have huge data of 1200 rows and 17 columns. I want to plot the graph for entire data for country and population.

When I am trying to work with below code I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Canada'
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd # for dataframes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting graphs
import seaborn as sns # for plotting graphs
import datetime as dt

data = pd.read_excel("TestData.xls")

plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 6))
n=0

for x in ['Country', 'Product', 'Sales']:
    n += 1
    plt.subplot(1,3,n)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5)
    sns.distplot(data[x], bins=20)
    plt.title('Displot of {}'.format(x))
plt.show()
```

Comment: the error is too straightforward you cant plot categorical values using distplot, you can use countplot for categorical features

Comment: Please show the context of `TestData.xls`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the [seaborn distplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) will soon be deprecated. You might want to switch to [displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) or [histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot).

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing an object of type `str` as the first argument in the [`seaborn.distplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) method, make sure that the string is in the format of an integer or float.

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd # for dataframes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting graphs
import seaborn as sns # for plotting graphs
import datetime as dt

data = pd.read_excel("TestData.xls")

plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 6))
n=0

for x in ['Country', 'Product', 'Sales']:
    n += 1
    plt.subplot(1,3,n)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5)
    a = data[x]
    if a.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
        sns.distplot(a, bins=20)
    else:
        print(f"{a} is not a float.")
    plt.title('Displot of {}'.format(x))
plt.show()
```

But do note from the linked documentation:

> **Warning**
>
> This function is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. >Please adapt your code to use one of two new functions:
>
> [`displot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), a figure-level function with a similar flexibility over the kind of plot to draw
>
> [`histplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot), an axes-level function for plotting histograms, including with kernel density smoothing

Comment: Hi, I am getting below error.                                                                                              f'For argument "{arg_name}" expected type bool, received '
ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type int.

Comment: @ADSKUL Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49265766/13552470

Comment: Let me check @Ann Zen.