# Update pandas DataFrame based on a different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames:

df1

```
key    id    count
100    9821   7
200    9813   10
```

df2

```
nodekey    nodeid    
100        9821   
200        9813
```

If the nodekey+nodeid in df2 match key+id in df1, count in df1 has to be set to 0. So, the result of the example above should be;

```
key    id    count
100    9821   0
200    9813   0
```

I tried the following (matching on key and nodekey only, as a test) but receive an error:

```
df1['count']=np.where((df1.key == df2.nodekey),0)

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

Suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266344/np-where-not-working-in-my-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
df1.loc[df1[['key', 'id']].transform(tuple,1).isin(df2[['nodekey', 'nodeid']].transform(tuple,1)), "count"] = 0
```

which is basically using

```
df.loc[mask, 'count']=0
```

where `mask` is `True` for rows where tuple `('key', 'id')` matches any tuple `('nodekey', 'nodeid')`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the dataframes using the left merge (the rows that are present in df1 but not in df2 will be filled with `nan`s):

```
combined = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['key', 'id'],
                         right_on=['nodekey', 'nodeid'], how='left')
```

Update the counts for the rows that are non-`nan`:

```
combined.loc[combined.nodekey.notnull(), 'count'] = 0
```

Cleanup the unwanted columns:

```
combined.drop(['nodekey', 'nodeid'], axis=1, inplace=True)
#   key    id  count
#0  100  9821      0
#1  200  9813      0
#2  300  9855      7
```